# Plotting data for each county using plotly in R without using geocode

Tags: r, maps, plotly, r-plotly

I have some data that I want to visualize using `plotly`. The location information in my dataset is limited to the state and county information i.e. no coordinates. I've tried to get coordinates from `ggplot2::map_data('county')` for each of the locations that I have but it doesn't seem to work:

DATA:

```
> dput(rd2[1:10])
structure(list(utility_name = c("Arizona Public Service Co", 
"Arizona Public Service Co", "AES Alamitos LLC", "AES Huntington Beach LLC", 
"Los Angeles Department of Water & Power", "PSEG Power Connecticut LLC", 
"Tampa Electric Co", "Indianapolis Power & Light Co", "NRG Canal LLC", 
"Nantucket Electric Co"), plant_name = c("Ocotillo", "Ocotillo", 
"AES Alamitos LLC", "AES Huntington Beach LLC", "Scattergood", 
"Bridgeport Station", "Big Bend", "Eagle Valley (IN)", "Canal", 
"Nantucket"), state = c("AZ", "AZ", "CA", "CA", "CA", "CT", "FL", 
"IN", "MA", "MA"), county = c("Maricopa", "Maricopa", "Los Angeles", 
"Orange", "Los Angeles", "Fairfield", "Hillsborough", "Morgan", 
"Barnstable", "Nantucket"), current_year = c(2019, 2018, 2020, 
2020, 2020, 2019, 2021, 2018, 2019, 2019), prime_mover = c("GT", 
"GT", "CT", "CT", "CT", "CT", "GT", "CT", "GT", "GT"), mw = c(485.7, 
323.8, 462, 462, 230, 375.7, 784, 414, 330, 15.4)), .Names = c("utility_name", 
"plant_name", "state", "county", "current_year", "prime_mover", 
"mw"), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000000000120788>)
```

CODE:

```
library(data.table)
coord_data <- as.data.table(map_data('county'))
coord_data[subregion %in% unique(rd2$county)]
```

OUTPUT:

```
> coord_data[subregion %in% unique(rd2$county)]
Empty data.table (0 rows) of 6 cols: long,lat,group,order,region,subregion
```

Perhaps `subregion` in `map_data` is not the county name. Any suggestions on how to plot this? All examples on the plotly website ([county](https://plot.ly/r/county-level-choropleth/), [scatter](https://plot.ly/r/scatter-plots-on-maps/), [bubble](https://plot.ly/r/bubble-maps/)) are with exact geographical coordinates. I don't want to use `ggmap:geocode` because based on my past experience it fails often even when I'm under the query limit and the time between calls is greater than the specified threshold.

Comment: your 'county' seems to line up with 'subregion' from `map_data` but the state names you have are abbreviated whereas they are written in full in the dataset you want to join. You'll need to do a bit of preprocessing before you can use your code.

Comment: Figured it out - there was a mismatch because `rd2$county` was in sentence case, using `tolower` got me what I wanted. Thanks anyway!

Comment: I would warn against just using `county` to match on - there are a lot of duplicate county names in there where different states have the same county name. There are 32 states with `washington` subregions, 26 `jefferson`, 25 `franklin` etc...

Comment: You're correct. Thanks!